# Rails 3.0 Missing stylesheets and javascript on Heroku Cedar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, precompile

I am using Rails 3.0.20 on Heroku. I have multiple environments of the same app running great in the bamboo stack. I was recently forced into using the Cedar stack and all of my stylesheets and javascripts are not being served. I am not using 3.1 so I don't have an "asset pipeline" and run rake assets:precompile doesn't work.

This is the content of my gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.20'
gem 'rake', '0.8.7' 
gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6' 
gem 'devise', '1.4.1' 
gem 'tabs_on_rails'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'
gem 'cancan'
gem "nested_has_many_through"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "acts_as_list"
gem "meta_where"
gem "meta_search"
gem "high_voltage"
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.4.1"
gem "fastercsv"
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'heroku', "~> 2.39.3"
gem 'heroku-api'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem 'rack', '1.2.5' 
gem 'hirefireapp'
gem 'httparty'
gem "doc_raptor"
gem 'exceptional'
gem 'pg'
```

Any ideas? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Look at https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor#rails-4-serve-static-assets

and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#rails-3-x-applications

Specifically the static assets plugin, plugin injection, and rails3_static_assets gem, and especially

> config.serve_static_assets = true

in production.rb environment.